# How should I refactor an eval loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I inherited a codebase that has this style of code and no tests:

```
  var series1 = [];
  var series2 = [];
  var series3 = [];
  var series4 = [];
  var series5 = [];
  var series6 = [];
  var series7 = [];
  var series8 = [];
  for (var y = 1; y <= seriesData.length; y++) {
      // columns are series
      eval("series" + y).push({
        label: "series" + y,
        lineColor: colorArr[seriesData[y - 1].colorIndex],
        x: sampleTime,
        y: rows[x][seriesData[y - 1].index]
      });
  }
```

The main problem is that we're going to start accommodating more than 8 sets of data. Personally, I don't really appreciate this style of code, and I've read the `eval` function can be harmful in JS. Is there a better way to refactor this?

What I've tried:

```
  let multiarr = []
  for (var y = 1; y <= seriesData.length; y++) {
    // columns are series
    let arr = [];
    arr.push({
      label: "series" + y,
      lineColor: colorArr[seriesData[y - 1].colorIndex],
      x: sampleTime,
      y: rows[x][seriesData[y - 1].index]
    });

  }
  multiarr.push(arr);
```

Comment: Assuming they are globally declared, try bracket notation, e.g. `window['series' + y]`

Comment: @LGSon I really don't want to use the window object for this. I think there might be a better way to keep the integrity of the data without needing to add to window

Comment: If they are globally declared, they already belong to the `window` object

Comment: Following @LGSon's example, you could create another array that is a collection of the above arrays `var parentArrays = [series1, series2, ...];` followed by `parentArrays[y-1].add(...)`

Comment: Or, you could create an object which contains those arrays as properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial code seems a bit strange. You have a block of `series` arrays, but each one only gets pushed with a single item. Couldn't it simply be reduced to:

```
const result = seriesData.map((item, i) => ({
  label: `series${i + i}`,
  lineColor: colorArr[item.colorIndex],
  x: sampleTime,
  y: rows[x][item.index]
}))
```

If for some reason, you do actually need each of the items to themselves be an array, just do:

```
const multiarr = seriesData.map((item, i) => [{
  label: `series${i + i}`,
  lineColor: colorArr[item.colorIndex],
  x: sampleTime,
  y: rows[x][item.index]
}])
```

Comment: there's a typo in my original code, the push to multiarr  should've been out of the loop. I like this approach though

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all arrays in a single array and push by taking an index.

```
var series1 = [],
    series2 = [],
    series3 = [],
    series4 = [],
    series5 = [],
    series6 = [],
    series7 = [],
    series8 = [],
    data = [series1, series2, series3, series4, series5, series6, series7, series8];

for (var y = 0; y < seriesData.length; y++) {
    data[y].push({
        label: "series" + (y + 1),
        lineColor: colorArr[seriesData[y].colorIndex],
        x: sampleTime,
        y: rows[x][seriesData[y].index]
    });
}
```

Comment: this would work, but I'd like to get rid of the original series arrays. It's not scalable. Thank you

Comment: it depends, what you like to do with it later.

Comment: It's used a chart. Like I mentioned in the original question, we're allowing more than 8. If we add 100 more, then I would need to create up to `series99 = []` to get this to work.

Comment: but you do not write, what you like to do with it? the whole approach with single array is strange. (but anyway, with a missing target data structure, it is hard to answer...)

Comment: that's a great point. I'll need to write a better question in the future. Thanks for lending some help. I agree the approach is strange, trying to make it better